# Arithmetic on 'Single&' with Linq expression trees?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

In C#, I would like to construct an arithmetic expression with the Linq expression trees when working with `float` obtained from a `Span<float>` Attempting to use [Expression.Multiply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.multiply) fails with `InvalidOperationException` thrown with `The binary operator Multiply is not defined for the types 'System.Single&' and 'System.Single&'`.

The sub-expressions are `Single&` instead of `Single` value and produced with:

```
var val = Expression.Call(
   mySpan,
   typeof(Span<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(float).GetMethod("get_Item"),
   myIndex)
```

Do do I convert `Single&` to `Single`? or alternatively, is there a more idiomatic way to call the indexer of a `Span<float>`?

Comment: How about constructing [`ConstantExpression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.constantexpression?view=netframework-4.7.2) using [`Expression.Constant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.constant?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Constant_System_Object_System_Type_)?

Comment: The `float` expressions are not constants.

Comment: What is this that you're trying to achieve? Can you post some sample data and operation you're willing to perform?

Comment: Have you tried this? ```Expression.Lambda<Func<float>>(Expression.Add(
                Expression.Constant(1.5f),
                Expression.Constant(2f)
            )).Compile()()```

Comment: Can you give more complete source code so we can try to run the code? Preferably with input and expected output.